# GTest compile error during in ROS catkin_ws

Tags: raspberry-pi, compile, raspbian

I'm trying to compile a catkin workspace but I keep getting this error message (or messages). Posting here as well as ROS Answers because it looks like the error is contained within gtest as opposed to the ROS package.

So far I've tried:

1. Building and installing gtest from source

and

2. Building the package using C++11

Both have yielded the same error message. Online, I have been unable to find anyone with a solution to the matter.

Trying to build my workspace using

```
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/kinetic
```

but I keep getting the following error while it's building camera_info_manager:

```
==> Processing catkin package: 'camera_info_manager'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_info_manager'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_info_manager'
[ 16%] Building CXX object gtest/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 50%] Built target camera_info_manager
In file included from /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc:42:0:
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc: In destructor ‘virtual testing::Test::~Test()’:
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc:1897:10: error: type ‘const class testing::internal::scoped_ptr<testing::internal::GTestFlagSaver>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
   delete gtest_flag_saver_;
          ^
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc: At global scope:
/usr/src/gtest/src/gtest.cc:2177:1: error: prototype for ‘testing::TestInfo::TestInfo(const string&, const string&, const char*, const char*, testing::internal::TypeId, testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)’ does not match any in class ‘testing::TestInfo’
 TestInfo::TestInfo(const std::string& a_test_case_name,
 ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:40:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:58,
                 from /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc:39:
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:772:3: error: candidates are: testing::TestInfo::TestInfo(const testing::TestInfo&)
   GTEST_DISALLOW_COPY_AND_ASSIGN_(TestInfo);
   ^
In file included from /usr/src/gtest/src/gtest-all.cc:39:0:
/usr/local/include/gtest/gtest.h:728:3: error:                 testing::TestInfo::TestInfo(const string&, const string&, const char*, const char*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, testing::internal::TypeId, testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)
   TestInfo(const std::string& test_case_name,
   ^


//------------------------------------------------------------------
// and a lot more of similar syntax-related issues
//------------------------------------------------------------------


    gtest/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'gtest/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o' failed
make[2]: *** [gtest/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1463: recipe for target 'gtest/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [gtest/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'camera_info_manager': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/catkin_ws/build_isolated/camera_info_manager && /opt/ros/kinetic/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out

```
if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
find_package(rostest)
  # Unit test uses gtest, but needs rostest to create a ROS environment.
  # Hence, it must be created as a normal executable, not using
  # catkin_add_gtest() which runs an additional test without rostest.
  add_executable(unit_test tests/unit_test.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(unit_test ${PROJECT_NAME} ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

in camera_info_manager's CMakeLists.txt. As far as I know this just disables unit testing for the package, but I'm largely unaware of the consequences of doing this.